# htaccess rewrite matching an exact query string

Tags: .htaccess

I'm attempting to redirect requests for `main/WinnersDetails.asp?ID=167` to `http://www.the-domain-name.org.uk/winners/simon-bingham.html`. However, my rewrite rule isn't working.

```
RewriteRule ^main/WinnersDetails.asp?ID=167$ http://www.the-domain-name.org.uk/winners/simon-bingham.html [R=301]
```

I think it's the query string part of the url that is causing the redirect to fail, but I'm not sure how to amend the rule to make it work.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3):

You can't match against a query string inside a rewrite rule. You need to match against the `%{QUERY_STRING}` variable in a rewrite condition:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^ID=167$ 
RewriteRule ^main/WinnersDetails.asp$ http://www.the-domain-name.org.uk/winners/simon-bingham.html? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Ideal. Thanks for your help. For reference I appended ? to the new url to prevent the query string being appended.